# Lex/flex program to count ids, statements, keywords, operators etc

Tags: c, compiler-construction, tokenize, flex-lexer

```
%{
#undef yywrap
#define yywrap() 1
#include<stdio.h>
  int statements = 0;
  int ids = 0;
  int assign = 0;
  int rel = 0;
  int keywords = 0;
  int integers = 0; 
%}
DIGIT [0-9]
LETTER [A-Za-z]
TYPE int|char|bool|float|void|for|do|while|if|else|return|void
%option yylineno
%option noyywrap

%%
\n {statements++;}
{TYPE} {/*printf("%s\n",yytext);*/keywords++;}
(<|>|<=|>=|==) {rel++;}
'#'/[a-zA-Z0-9]*    {;}
[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]* {printf("%s\n",yytext);ids++;}
= {assign++;}
[0-9]+ {integers++;}
.      {;}

%%
void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  FILE *fh;
  if (argc == 2 && (fh = fopen(argv[1], "r"))) {
    yyin = fh;
  }
  yylex();
  printf("statements = %d ids = %d assign = %d rel = %d keywords = %d integers = %d \n",statements,ids,assign,rel,keywords,integers);
}
```

//Input file.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(){
    float a123;
    char a;
    char b123;
    char c;
    int ab[5];
    int bc[2];
    int ca[7];
    int ds[4];
    for( a = 0; a < 5 ;a++)
     printf("%d ", a);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
include
stdio
h
main
a123
a
b123
c
ab
bc
ca
ds
a
a
a
printf
d
a
statements = 14 ids = 18 assign = 1 rel = 3 keywords = 11 integers = 7
```

I am printing the identifiers on the go. `#include<stdio.h>` is being counted as identifier. How do I avoid this?

I have tried `'#'/[a-zA-Z0-9]*    {;}` rule:action pair but it is still being counted as identifier. How is the file being tokenized?

Also the `%d` string in `printf` is being counted as an identifier. I have explicitly written that identifiers should only begin with letters, then why is `%d` being inferred as identifier?

Comment: Preprocessor directives are always on one line. The include directive starts with a `#` the keyword `include` and a string representing a path placed between angular brackets. The `%d` in the string  gets parsed as `d` because the `%` gets dropped. The content of the string literal gets parsed because you do not detect string literals. String literals are anything between `"` except  `"` (except if escaped `\"` but that's another can of worms). But you are on a good path from last time.

Comment: So how do I avoid `#include<stdio.h>` and "%d"? I am getting `stdio` and `h` as keywords, how does that fit the definition that I have given? What happened to the `.` in between?

Comment: You can't count statements with *lex/flex*. You'll need to parse for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. > I have tried `'#'/[a-zA-Z0-9]* {;}` rule:action pair but it [`include`] is still being counted as identifier. How is the file being tokenized?

   Tokens are recognized one at a time. Each token starts where the previous token finished.

   `'#'/[a-zA-Z0-9]*` matches <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>#</kbd><kbd>'</kbd>  provided it is followed by `[a-zA-Z0-9]*`. You probably meant `"#"/[a-zA-Z0-9]*` (with double quotes) which would match a <kbd>#</kbd>, again provided it is followed by a letter or digit. Note that only the <kbd>#</kbd> is matched; the pattern after the `/` is "trailing context", which is basically a lookahead assertion. In this case, the lookahead is pointless because `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` can match the empty string, so any <kbd>#</kbd> would be matched. In any event, after the <kbd>#</kbd> is matched as a token, the scan continues at the next character. So the next token would be `include`.

   Because of the typo, that pattern does not match. (There are no apostrophes in the source.) So what actually matches is your "fallback" rule: the rule whose pattern is `.`. (We call this a fallback rule because it matches anything. Really, it should be `.|\n`, since `.` matches anything but a newline, but as long as you have some rule which matches a newline character, it's acceptable to use `.`. If you don't supply a fallback rule, one will be inserted automatically by flex with the action `ECHO`.)

   Thus, the <kbd>#</kbd> is ignored (just as it would have been if you'd written the rule as intended) and again the scan continues with the token `include`.

   If you wanted to ignore the entire preprocessor directive, you could do something like

   ^[[:blank:]]#.* { ; }
2. > (from a comment) I am getting `stdio` and `h` as keywords, how does that fit the definition that I have given? What happened to the `.` in between?

   After the <kbd><</kbd> is ignored by the fallback rule, `stdio` is matched. Since `[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*` doesn't match anything other than letters and digits, the <kbd>.</kbd> is not considered part of the token. Then the <kbd>.</kbd> is matched and ignored by the fallback rule, and then `h` is matched.
3. > Also the `%d` string in `printf` is being counted as an identifier.

   Not really. The <kbd>%</kbd> is explicitly ignored by the fallback rule (as was the <kbd>"</kbd>) and then the `d` is marched as an identifier. If you want to ignore words in string literals, you will have to recognise and ignore string literals.

Comment: @piepi: It's just an informal description. Normally, flex rulesets end with a rule whose pattern is `.|\n`, which matches any single character; we call that the "fallback" rule because if nothing else works, the lexer falls back to that rule. Sometimes it is possible to use the simpler pattern `.`, because some other rule matches `\n` (as in your example), but it's better style to write the fallback pattern out in full, just in case. Unless you specify `%option nodefault`, flex will insert a default fallback rule whose action is `ECHO`.

Answer (score 0):

The #include directive is a preprocessor directive and is thus preprocessed by the preprocessor. The preprocessor includes the header file and removes the #include directive And thus after preprocessing when the program is given to compiler as input it doesn't have any preprocessor directives like #include.
 So you don't need to write code to detect #include because neither compiler ever sees it nor it is designed to tokenize #include directive.

References: [Is #include a token of type keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30106975/is-include-a-token-of-type-keyword)

Answer (score 0):

adding the following line in the rules section works for me:

#.*   ;

Here rule is #.* and action is ;. The #.* will catch the line starting with # and ; will just do nothing so basically this would ignore the line starting with #.